# How do I get URLs only from from a string with HTML tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this code here which detects URLs within a string which contains HTML content

```
$regex = "/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
                preg_match_all($regex, $desc, $url);
                print_r($url);
```

The code works great, however the `print_r($url)` returns URLs like:

```
http://url.com/</p>
```

The `</p>` is simply there to close the `<p>` tag, but I don't want it in my URL.

How could I block that out?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Parse your HTML first, then run the link-finder on the text?

Comment: How would I parse the HTML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: I am going to use the strip_tags function instead I think. I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `strip_tags` function to remove all HTML tags then `preg_match_all()` to get each URL:

```
$regex = "/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
preg_match_all($regex, strip_tags(html_entity_decode($desc)), $url);
print_r($url);
```

I hope this helps others in the future!

Peter